# Why google app engine stop auto scaling?

Tags: google-app-engine, autoscaling

I was trying google app engine and data store these 2 days, and I did some jmeter load testing. I noticed that everything runs fine at the beginning of the day, but later the instance auto scaling stop working. I already upgraded to the paid account, and setup the billing account to pay for the use.

In my jmeter test, the app engine can handle 250+ request per second at the beginning. After some like 10k requests, the engine start slow down to 10 rps. I checked the instances from console. It seems when it slow down, there is only 1 instance working, auto scaling seems stop working.

Anyone have some idea what's happened there? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your app engine is running out of resources for it to start auto scaling?

JMeter is notorious for NOT scaling. Depending on the JVM settings and the machine's hardware capacity, JMeter's request per second could get pegged after a certain level. Make sure your JMeter instance has sufficient resource and also that it's JVM is not in GC frenzy mode during the test.

Comment: Shouldn't be the jmeter issue. I restarted jmeter, and the problem still exist. And the GAE auto scaling was working well in the first 2 runs (each with 4500 requests).

Comment: Ok, it seems this is actually the issue of JMeter. Somehow it use up connection resources or whatever, and can't release them even it quit. After restarting my computer, it start working again. Anyone know how to solve this? or any tools that can free the resources used up my JMeter?

Comment: I am glad you found the root cause of the problem. Kindly up vote the answer if you found my answer correct. Regarding how to tune JMeter, I would suggest you to post a separate question as it would help the broader community.